# Informatica - Using single output port multiple times

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I know this may seem like a basic task, but I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

I have an output port after a set of transformations (Filter/Joins/Aggregates/Joins/Filters) and would like to use an output port twice going into 2 separate transformations.

Is this possible from all transformations?

Anything I need to watch out for?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can connect the output port to two separate transformations. No problem. But, they should remain in separate pipelines for the rest of the mapping. If you need to bring the two ports back to a single transformation again, you would require transformations that support multiple input groups like, Joiner, Union etc.

Answer (score 0):

Below are validation rules for connecting ports to downstream ports:

1. You can only link ports with compatible data types.
2. You cannot connect an active transformation and a passive transformation to the same downstream transformation.
3. You cannot connect more than one active transformation to the same downstream transformation or transformation input group. Only way to do it using joiner with sorted ports.